# Print new line ONLY at the end of a vector - "if" statement outside of a "for" loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, if-statement, vector

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {

std::cout << "Please, enter the number of iterations: ";    //Inputs

int iterations;
std::cin >> iterations;

std::cout << "Which term would you like to know: ";

int term;
std::cin >> term;   //End inputs

std::vector<int> series;     //definition of vector "series"

for (int n = 1;  n <= iterations; n++) {    //creation of "series"

    int next = (2 * n - 3);
    series.push_back(next);

}

std::cout << "The value of term "   //prints the n term
          << term
          << " is: "
          << series[term-1]         //term-1 "adjust" the indexing
          << std::endl;

std::cout << "The entire serie up to "
          << iterations
          << " terms is: ";

for (int i = 0;  i < series.size(); i++) {      //prints (elements of vector) "series"

    std::cout << series[i] << ' ';

    if (i == series.size()-1) {     //new line only at the end the series

        std::cout << std::endl; 
    }

}

return 0;

}
```

I got 9/10 with this comment: "if condition inside loop will only be satisfied once, but checked every time. Move outside of loop".
I really don't how could I place the if statement out of the loop.
The scope of that for-if statement is to add a new line only at the end of the vector "series".
I can't think about anything else but for sure I'm experienced enough and there is another more elegant solution.
I'm asking here because I have to submit another assignment and I don't want to submit it with the same error.

PS: the other comment was: light over-commenting. Did I really commented to much?

Comment: You don't need that `if` at all. e.g. `return 0` happens "only at the end of the series".

Comment: The `if` block is only checked at the _end_ of the iteration, and the only entry condition is if you are servicing the _last_ element. That's semantically identical to _not_ having an `if` block at all -- and moving the contents to immediately after the loop (e.g. unconditionally call `std::cout << std::endl` after the `for` instead of conditionally checking the last element per iteration.)

Comment: And yes, you are adding pointless comments, e.g.: `std::vector<int> series;     //definition of vector "series"` is obvious to anyone who write C++ code

Comment: To add on to the commenting thing... you can also write self-commenting code... so to create your series or print your series you can create functions called `seriesCreation`, `printSeries`, or `initializeSeries`  This would help with some of the pointless comments and still explain what you are doing.  Readable code with meaningful variable names is much better then obvious comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print the `endl` at the end of the `for loop`, so you can to add the line of `endl` when you go out from the loop and remove the line at the for loop, **it will give you the same result**

***The code:***

```
for (int n = 1;  n <= iterations; n++) {    //creation of "series"

    int next = (2 * n - 3);
    series.push_back(next);

}

std::cout << "The value of term "   //prints the n term
          << term
          << " is: "
          << series[term-1]         //term-1 "adjust" the indexing
          << std::endl;

std::cout << "The entire serie up to "
          << iterations
          << " terms is: ";

for (int i = 0;  i < series.size(); i++) {      //prints (elements of vector) "series"

    std::cout << series[i] << ' ';
}
std::cout << std::endl; 
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to print a newline after the last element. Here, you are checking for each element if it is the last. However, you don't need to do that.

Another way to do "After the last element" is "after all elements", so after the loop. Just process all the elements with the for loop, then print the newline.

I'm not giving the code, since it is an assignment, but this should be clear enough.

As for commenting: don't document the obvious. Of course, for different levels, obvious is something different. But for the declaration of the "series" vector, the comment doesn't add anything to the code, for instance.